# Using $.ajax() call in jQuery

Tags: jquery

When using `$.ajax()` to call a web service, can I use the following code to check the type of data returned by the web service in the `dataFilter` parameter like so

```
$.ajax({
    uri: '/',
    dataFilter: function(data, type) {
        if (type == 'text/xml')
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            // do something else
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you try it and see for yourself ?

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
i think this url,can help

Type: Function( String data, String type ) => Object
A function to be used to handle the raw response data of XMLHttpRequest.This is a pre-filtering function to sanitize the response. You should return the sanitized data. The function accepts two arguments: The raw data returned from the server and the 'dataType' parameter.

i test you code.

```
alert(type);
```

it will web alert Undefined

Comment: I think the OP already knows that, and it doesn't really answer the question.